# I need some advice to alter my sql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *,round(6378.138*2*asin(sqrt(pow(sin( (lat*pi()/180-0*pi()/180)/2),2)+cos(lat*pi()/180)*cos(0*pi()/180)* pow(sin( (lng*pi()/180-0*pi()/180)/2),2)))*1000) AS juli    
            FROM `institution` a 
            WHERE round(6378.138*2*asin(sqrt(pow(sin( (lat*pi()/180-0*pi()/180)/2),2)+cos(lat*pi()/180)*cos(0*pi()/180)* pow(sin( (lng*pi()/180-0*pi()/180)/2),2)))*1000)<1000000
            ORDER BY juli ASC
            LIMIT 10
```

I think it is bad.Any advice?

Comment: What is the query supposed to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: @LukasKabrt: It appears to be calculating some kind of great circle distance between two geolocations (as indicated by lat/lng vars and trig functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of `0*x` operations, which obviously aren't contributing anything. I'd simplify those out first. Also you seem to be doing a heck of a lot of `deg->rad` transformations that could probably be improved by just storing your data in radians in the first place.

Comment: It is just an exmple, I store `lng` `lat`,I  want to find places in distance range

Comment: Sure, but you can still convert your lat/lng to radians to save some cycles and query complexity. I still don't see why you need the 0*x operations though.

Comment: I am not sure how to convert that,0 is nothing but a test,I do not have a real geolocation infomation.

Answer (score 0):

I think its looking fine but there is no need `ASC` use only :-

```
ORDER BY juli
```

Comment: Don't you think round(whatever) which is used twice not fine?